# In what thread will calculations be performed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have following classes for example:

```
class CalculatorA:
    def functionA(self):
        #some calculations

class CalculatorB:
    def functionB(self):
        #some calculations

class CalculatorC:
    def functionC(self):
        #some calculations

class Aggregator:
    def __init__(self, objectA, objectB, objectC):
        self.objectA = objectA
        self.objectB = objectB
        self.objectC = objectC

    def aggregator_function(self):
        self.objectA.functionA()
        self.objectB.functionB()
        self.objectC.functionC()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,
                 objectA,
                 objectB,
                 objectC):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.objectA = objectA
        self.objectB = objectB
        self.objectC = objectC

    def run(self):
        agregator = Aggregator(self.objectA, 
                                self.objectB, 
                                self.objectC)
        agregator.aggregator_function()
```

My `main()` function:

```
def main():
    objectA = CalculatorA()
    objectB = CalculatorB()
    objectC = CalculatorC()

worker = Worker(objectA, objectB, objectC)
worker.start()
```

I create objects of `CalculatorA, CalculatorB, CalculatorC` classes in the `main()` function and pass variables as parameters 
to the constructor of `Worker`. An object of the `Worker` class saves them. Later it passes the variables to the constructor of an `Aggregator` object in the `run()` function. It creates an `Aggregator` object in a separate thread of calculations. `Aggregator` calls functions `functionA(), functionB(), functionC()`.

My question is, in what thread calculations of the functions `functionA(), functionB(), functionC()` will be performed? Will they be performed 
in the Worker thread, or in the main thread? Should I use `threading.local` storage, if in the main thread?

Comment: Why would they be performed in the main thread? The worker is the one that calls `aggregator_function()`, and that's where you call `functionA()`, etc.

Comment: Do you think that objects remember which thread they were created in, and run their functions in that thread? Functions run in whatever thread they're called in, objects don't change that.

Comment: @Barmar I just wanted to be sure, that's why I asked.

Comment: Why not finding out yourself by adding `print(threading.get_ident())` in various parts of your code?

Comment: @CristiFati Because I had a similar situation and the function returned the same identifier. That confused me and I decided to ask people. Maybe that code was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are called in whatever thread the calling function is run in. The fact that they're object methods doesn't change this.

Since `self.objectA.functionA()` is called from `aggregator.aggregator_function()`, and this is called from the `Worker.run()` method, it gets called in the `Worker` thread.

Answer (score 1):

They'll all be run from the worker thread.

You should be able to verify this with something like `print(threading.get_ident())`.